# What HD and Size does a Vampire's "Become the Swarm" Feat give?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, undead, swarm

The question is quite simple but I've looked and can find no clear answer.

Lets say a 10HD vampire has the [Become the Swarm](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/fire-mountain-games/become-the-swarm/) feat; do you calculate the damage and size via the [Swarm Damage by Size table](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types/#TOC-Swarm-Subtype) in the swarm subtype, or do you not? And now that I think about it, do you also add any ability bonus to the swarm form's damage?

Answer (score 1):

## The same

The become the Swarm feat states explicitly, that the Hitpoints of the swarm and those of the vampire are identical:

> This swarm has a number of hit points equal to the vampire, and any damage done to the swarm affects the vampire‘s hit point total.

Save for the Hitpoints, the stat block becomes that of the swarm for combat:

> a vampire cannot use any of its natural or special attacks [...] it gains the movement, natural weapons, and extraordinary special abilities of the swarm into which it has transformed.
>
> [It] retains all of its usual special qualities.

So a 10-HD Vampire becomes a 10-HD Bat Swarm with all the natural abilities of a 10-HD Bat swarm, with the exact abilities specified.

Comment: This could be improved by providing what a 10HD Bat swarm statblock actually has, at least for damage and special abilities